# how to solve this problem in R: In while (t <= cc[i]) { ... : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r

I choose division
0 = d0 < d1 < . . . < dm =tau,
and then, for t ∈ (dj−1, dj ] the intensity function λ(t) is equal to λj.

My data set

```
parlocation<-125.0949
parscale<-34.98857
tau<-365
trendlinier$coefficients[1]<-78.37888
trendlinier$coefficients[2]<--5.809776
lambdaj<-c(8.665351,178.934646,161.189187,57.680814,43.540869,102.405160,108.003538,157.690273,138.600075,269.314099,353.897407,197.891330)
deretbln2<-c(0,31,62,90,121,151,182,212,243,274,304,335,365)
```

and then, I make this function for λ(t) in R

```
lambda2 <- function(t){for (i in 1:12) {while (t <=deretbln2[i]) {return(lambdaj[i-1])}}}
```

I also make this function in R

```
FU0 <- function(t){pcauchy((tau-t)*trendlinier$coefficients[1]/((trendlinier$coefficients[2]*t)+trendlinier$coefficients[1]),location=parlocation,scale=parscale)}

intensityIBNR <- function(t){lambda2(t)*(1-FU0(t))}
```

when I run this code

```
c <- integrate(f=intensityIBNR, lower=0, upper=tau,
           subdivisions=200)
```

its result like this

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In while (t <= deretbln2[i]) { ... :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Please, help me to solve this problem..

Comment: Sriviona, you should not post the same question twice. Since we've made more progress in the other one, I suggest you delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

a few remarks on the side:

1) the object `trendlinier` is non-existant in your MWE; hence `trendlinier$coefficients[1]` should terminate with an error. We need to instantiat that object first as

```
trendlinier <- list(coefficients = NULL)
```

2) I would recommend not using `t` or `c` as object names in *R*, since both are used for function names; rather use `tt` or `cc` (or better, variable names that have more meaning); Let's stay with `tt` and `cc` (and leave the `lambda2`- function on the side), we'll obtain

```
parlocation<-125.0949
parscale<-34.98857
tau<-365
trendlinier$coefficients[1]<-78.37888
trendlinier$coefficients[2]<--5.809776
lambdaj<-c(8.665351,178.934646,161.189187,57.680814,43.540869,102.405160,108.003538,157.690273,138.600075,269.314099,353.897407,197.891330)
deretbln2<-c(0,31,62,90,121,151,182,212,243,274,304,335,365)

FU0 <- function(tt){pcauchy((tau-tt)*trendlinier$coefficients[1]/((trendlinier$coefficients[2]*tt)+trendlinier$coefficients[1]),location=parlocation,scale=parscale)}
intensityIBNR <- function(tt){lambda2(tt)*(1-FU0(tt))}
cc <- integrate(f=intensityIBNR, lower=0, upper=tau, subdivisions=200)
```

Now, note that *R*'s indices start at 1; that is regarding the `for`-loop in the `lambda2`-function, for `i=1`, there is no `lambdaj[i-1]`. You need to consider and implement different routines for `i=1` and `i>1` (or add a default value to `lambdaj`; e.g., `lambdaj <- c(0, lambdaj)` if `0` is a reasonble value in this case). (Another remark on the side: the statement `while (expression) { return }` is an unusual implementation of the `if`-clause). If you prefer not altering `lambdaj` you could use

```
lambda2 <- function(tt){for (i in 1:12) {if (i == 1) return(0) else if (tt <= deretbln2[i]) return(lambdaj[i-1])}}
```

P.S.: that is not the best way to typeset *R*-Code (cf., [Hadley's style guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html))

Comment: Big thank you and warm regards Mr. Tom,
for the detail my problem maybe you can see in new post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185747/how-to-solve-this-problem-in-r-in-while-t-cci-the-condition-has-le

Thanks You Mr. Tom