# how to solve this problem in R: In while (t <= cc[i]) { … : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, function, loops, numerical-integration

big thank you and warm regards for the answer Mr. Tom, for the detail problem may you can help me the following step :

I have a problem with R Program,

first, I make a trendlinier (At+B) from this data set

```
timedelay<-c(76.77,65.88,60.96,51.61,48.72,39.86,35.43,33.36,30.32,23.96,16.95,3.564)
timedelayts<-ts(timedelay,start=c(2011,1),freq=12)
plot(timedelayts,ylab="Time Delay",col="blue")
time=ts(1:length(timedelayts),start=c(2011,1),freq=12)
trendlinier<-lm(timedelayts~time)
trendlinier
Call:
Coefficients:
(Intercept)         time
78.38              -5.81
Avalue<-(-5.81)
Bvalue<-78.38
```

From `fitdist` I get a cauchy distribution and result like this

```
fitcauchy<-fitdist(filterdelay, "cauchy")
summary(fitcauchy)
Fitting of the distribution ' cauchy ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters : 
          estimate Std. Error
location 125.08885   2.215711
scale     34.97553   2.143992
Loglikelihood:  -3436.131   AIC:  6876.262   BIC:  6884.852 
Correlation matrix:
          location     scale
location 1.0000000 0.2219629
scale    0.2219629 1.0000000
```

and then I put parameter `location` and `scale` in

```
parlocation<-fitcauchy$estimate[1]
parscale<-fitcauchy$estimate[2]
```

After that, I make a function

```
FU0 <- function(tt){pcauchy((tau-tt)*Bvalue/((Avalue*tt)+Bvalue),location=parlocation,scale=parscale)}
```

then, I have `lambdaj=λj` and `lambda2(tt)=λ(t)` and data set for `lambdaj` like this

```
lambdaj<-c(8.665351,178.934646,161.189187,57.680814,43.540869,102.405160,108.003538,157.690273,138.600075,269.314099,353.897407,197.891330)
```

with `λ1=8.665351`,`λ2=178.934646`,...,`λ2=197.891330`. Then, I have data set `sequenceday` like this

```
sequenceday<-c(0,31,62,90,121,151,182,212,243,274,304,335,365)
```

and then, I make this function for λ(tt) in R for implementation this formula,

division `0 = d0< d1=31 <d2=62 . . . < d12 =365`,

for tt ∈ (dj−1, dj ] the intensity function λ(tt) is equal to λj.

```
lambda2 <- function(tt){
  for (i in 1:(length(sequenceday))) {
    while (tt <=sequenceday[i]) {
      return(lambdaj[i-1])
    }
  }
}
```

I want to result that function following :

example:

"`tt` in a day, if I input 63 days to function `lambda2(63)` where 63 ∈ (d2=62, d3=90 ], then `lambda2(63)=λ3=161.189187`"

when I run function `lambda2(63)` in R, the result is:

```
> lambda2(63)
[1] 161.2404
```

until this step is run correctly,

so next step, I want to implementation `lambda2` into `integrate()` in R, with  the function `IntensityIBNR` Like this

```
intensityIBNR <- function(tt){lambda2(tt)*(1-FU0(tt))}
```

when I run this code

```
cc <- integrate(f=intensityIBNR, lower=0, upper=tau,
           subdivisions=200)
```

its result like this

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In while (tt<=sequenceday[i]) { ... :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Please, help me to solve this problem..

Comment: Can you please confirm that this is not a dupe of any of these? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+length+%3E+1+and+only+the+first+element+will+be+used

Comment: Is `while (t <= deretbln2[i])` your code? I don't see it in the question.

Comment: I'm so sorry, before I suggest from someone so I try his suggest. but still error. I thought my previous explanation about this problem might still be unclear, so I tried to explain this problem again. I really hope you can help me @r2evans

Comment: I don't have `fitdist`, what package is that from?

Comment: package `fitdistrplus`, you can see here about 'fitdist' https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fitdistrplus/versions/1.0-14/topics/fitdist

Comment: thankyou @r2evans. I am happy because you have responded to me. I need help.

Comment: What else? `Error in fitdist(filterdelay, "cauchy") : object 'filterdelay' not found`. Sriviona, it *really* helps when the code is reproducible, and really easy to lose focus (and attention) when unnecessary omissions occur.

Comment: Also, `tau` is missing.

Comment: Okay, so I replaced `filterdelay` with `timedelay`, and arbitrarily set `tau <- 10` to get things started. The culprit: your `lambda2` function is passed `tt` as a **vector**, not a single value. I think you need to explain what you think your `lambda2` function is supposed to be doing when it receives 21 values in a vector. ***This is the root of your problem.***

Comment: right, that lambda2 is the root of my problem.. so what I doing for solving this problem. because I have result of lambda2 is 1 value. 

I try this code :